# How to build a MPI program with VTK, Boost and SQLite3 library using CMake?

Tags: cmake, mpi

I would like to build a `MPI` program with `VTK`, `Boost` and `SQLite3` library using `CMake`. First, I built a simple `MPI` program without other libraries using a `CMakeLists.cmake` file like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(testMPI)

FIND_PATH(MPI_INTEL_C mpicc $ENV{PATH})
FIND_PATH(MPI_INTEL_CXX mpicxx $ENV{PATH})

IF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Intel MPI compiler is used.")    
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
ENDIF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)    
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${testMPI_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

SET(SRC_LIST testMPI.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(testMPI ${SRC_LIST})

FIND_PATH(MPI_H_INCLUDE mpi.h $ENV{PATH})
IF(NOT MPI_H_INCLUDE)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "mpi.h  not  found")
ENDIF(NOT MPI_H_INCLUDE)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_H_INCLUDE})

IF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(testMPI PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -i-dynamic)
ELSE(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)
    FIND_LIBRARY(MPI_CXX_LIB mpichcxx $ENV{PATH})
    IF(NOT MPI_CXX_LIB)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "mpich2 library not found")
    ENDIF(NOT MPI_CXX_LIB)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${MPI_CXX_LIB})

    FIND_LIBRARY(MPI_LIB mpich $ENV{PATH})
    IF(NOT MPI_LIB)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "mpich2 library not found")
    ENDIF(NOT MPI_LIB)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${MPI_LIB})
ENDIF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)
```

I used `mpirun -np 8 -nolocal -machinefile ./machinefile ./testMPI` to run the program successfully, and the returned `number of processes` was correct (=8).

And then, I just put some headers of `VTK`, `Boost` and `SQLite3` library into this simple program (.cpp), and used the following CMakeLists.cmake to find, include and link these libraries. The program was built successfully, also I used `mpirun -np 8 -nolocal -machinefile ./machinefile ./testMPI` to run this program, but the returned `number of processes` was wrong (=1). So how to build a MPI program with other libraries using CMake? Thank you in advance!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)    
PROJECT(testMPI)

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${testMPI_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(testMPI ${DIR_SRCS})    
install(TARGETS testMPI DESTINATION bin)

SET(VTK_DIR "/export/home/hh/hh/vtk/")   
SET(VTK_LIBRARIES libLSDyna.so libMapReduceMPI.so libmpistubs.so libvtkalglib.so libvtkCharts.so libvtkCommon.so libvtkDICOMParser.so libvtkexoIIc.so libvtkexpat.so libvtkFiltering.so libvtkfreetype.so libvtkftgl.so libvtkGenericFiltering.so libvtkGeovis.so libvtkGraphics.so libvtkhdf5_hl.so libvtkhdf5.so libvtkHybrid.so libvtkImaging.so libvtkInfovis.so libvtkIO.so libvtkjpeg.so libvtklibxml2.so libvtkmetaio.so libvtkNetCDF_cxx.so libvtkNetCDF.so libvtkpng.so libvtkproj4.so libvtkRendering.so libvtksqlite.so libvtksys.so libvtktiff.so libvtkverdict.so libvtkViews.so libvtkVolumeRendering.so libvtkWidgets.so libvtkzlib.so)

SET(VTK_LIBRARIES_DIRS)    
foreach(libs ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
    set(FOUND "FOUND-NOTFOUND")
    find_library(FOUND ${libs} "/export/home/hh/hh/vtk/lib/vtk-5.10")
    list(APPEND VTK_LIBRARIES_DIRS ${FOUND})
endforeach(libs)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
IF(VTK_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "VTK IS USED")
    INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "VTK IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(VTK_FOUND)   
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${VTK_LIBRARIES_DIRS})

LIST (APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/boost/include")
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/boost/lib")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
IF(Boost_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Boost IS USED")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
ELSE(Boost_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Boost IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)    
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include")
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib")    
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${testMPI_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED)    
IF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "SQLite3 IS USED")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "SQLite3 IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)    
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})

FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)

IF(MPI_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "MPI IS USED")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "MPI IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(MPI_FOUND)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testMPI ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Seriously, use FindMPI as answered in your other question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, use FindMPI could not solve this problem.

Comment: @Zulan, I updated the post, and used FindMPI, but still got a wrong returned number of processes.